# Customisable Canned Responses - shall we make a Gist for common comments?

Tags: discussion

As an addendum to [this topic](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1692/can-we-please-be-more-friendly-to-new-users) I am asking if it is time we made a Gist repo to fill up on some common responses for commenting on different post types. Such as new users not knowing "question format", "length of content" on questions, "Welcome to the site" comments etc.

Just to get us started here is an example:

https://gist.github.com/thopiddock/ee4894427d855b10f868

Comment: I'd note that both of your examples contain redundancies with the primarily-opinion-based close reason. The close reason text is displayed to the user, so any unofficial collection of pre-canned responses probably should not duplicate that information.

Comment: Noted but my examples are rough ones I've made on my lunch break, it's open to more suggestions of course.

Answer (score 1):

These comments are so specific to the question/comment/answer, it's a waste of time to save them; they'll likely never be used in exactly the same form again. I can guarantee you I wouldn't be looking in a repo for canned responses. I just write my own every time.

Comment: I think it *would* be useful to do this if we were instead discussing the need for a new close reason (since we are at our custom close reason cap). But I am sort of indifferent to the need to do it to augment existing reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I feel that rather than the system providing a set of canned responses the mod / user should be able to store their own set of responses and pull them out as appropriate.

The key here is that ...

1. users aren't met with a default response which comes across as rude
2. mods should be individual in their response showing their real attitude towards the community.

To me, a Gist doesn't feel like an improvement to the site (again personal opinion, totally subjective)

Comment: A gist is something we *can do*, however. We can't alter the site software.

Comment: Further, I doubt a proposal on the SE meta to support this would be met with any sort of encouragement: if you want to store per-user canned responses, you can store them yourself in a text file on your machine, your own personal gist, Dropbox, Google Docs, et cetera.

Comment: Then my response to that would be ... stop canned responses altogether. Mods should take the time to give an appropriate response given the context of the current question. I know I always do whatever the situation so why is your time more valuable than mine?

Comment: The boilerplate close reasons are available for *everybody* to use, and they *are* considered an appropriate response. That's why they exist (and we can alter some of them if needed, but I've seen no actual actionable suggestions to that end). They appear on *every* close, not just moderator ones. We are not going to stop using them, they are a network-wide feature. If you want to make a case for SE not having them any longer, you'll need to propose it at the SE meta.

Comment: To my mind they seem a little impersonal ... everything on SE should be user content IMO but i'm sure many don't agree and would happily justify it with reasons like "i don't have the time"

Comment: "I don't have the time" and "I don't have the time to manually write out *exactly the same comment* which is applicable to 95% of closed questions," are two very different things. The rationale for the closure text and UI is to help address the latter case. When you vote, you don't have to comment explaining why either. It would be pointless to require you to do so, 95% of the time users would simply write "+1!"

Comment: Exactly the same? Are you a robot?

Comment: I am not a robot, and as such I do not like to waste my time doing what I perceive to be silly things that a computer can do perfectly well for me. Manually typing: 'Questions about "how to get started," "what to learn next," or "which technology to use" are discussion-oriented questions which involve answers that are either based on opinion, or which are all equally valid. Those kinds of questions are outside the scope of this site. Visit our help center for more information.' every time is one such thing.